# How to build a library of reusable slides for PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, sharepoint, templates

Our company has recently had a rebrand and we are redesigning all our slide decks, we have about 100 unique slides that get used in various scenarios and sometimes not all slides are needed.

I'd like to create a library of individual slides, so that if someone wants to build a specific presentation very quickly with prepopulated information, they can.

I have created a template that has the company fonts and colours embedded into it, with a few standard layouts and this is shared on the company's Sharepoint - where people can access it through the templates tab in the app.

Does PP have such a feature that someone could grab a prebuilt slide and put it into their presentation with little effort?

Note: I have considered creating the slides within the slide master - but this will bloat the size of the template and the resulting file. And, although I could create master slides without images and heavy graphics, it also presents an NDA issue as some slides are only available through signing an NDA (someone could go into master and see this information)

Powerpoint version is the latest in Microsoft 365.

Comment: Which PowerPoint version?

Comment: Added to the question - latest on in Office 365

Comment: Have you looked at the Insert | New Slide | Reuse slides command?

Comment: PowerPoint does not have the ability to have saved slides as building blocks to insert. Best is like @SteveRindsberg said, save all the prebuilt slides (each with a descriptive filename) and use New Slide>Reuse Slides to insert them from the "prebuilt gallery directory" when needed

Comment: Who voted to close this for being opinion based? Yet another question that has nothing to do with opinions and may get closed if people confirm it blindly.

Comment: Apparently they changed their mind, or somebody else overrode them. The question's not closed.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, yes, this is probably the route I'm going to, seems like the only option, if a bit tedious to manage and navigate to.

Comment: Just to add an option that may or may not be of use: there are various commercial add-ins that give you expanded functionality above and (WAY!) beyond PPT's Reuse Slides feature. I have one that lets you set up source files that let users insert single slides, pre-chosen groups of slides, graphics, videos, sounds .... pretty much anything that PPT can add to a slide. If that might be a solution, you can reach me via the Contact link at https://www.pptools.com to arrange an online demo.  And it'll be a demo, not a high pressure sales pitch. I'm a lousy salesman. ;-)